# обновление таблицы SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, update

хочу обновить таблицу в SQL Server  во вложение фото помогите пожалуйста

```
update TICKET set voz_sub_som = (select foiz_sub * tarif_som / 100 AS "Total Cost" FROM  TICKET)
from TICKET
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `UPDATE ticket SET voz_sub_som = foiz_sub * tarif_som / 100 -- WHERE foiz_sub IS NOT NULL `

Answer (score 0):

сделал как Akina написала в комментариях все получилось всем спасибо за помощ

```
UPDATE ticket SET voz_sub_som = foiz_sub * tarif_som / 100 -- WHERE foiz_sub IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте перед вашей процедурой update, убрать NULL в foiz_sub

`update Ticket set foiz_sub=0  where foiz_sub is NULL`

Если вам NULL вообще не требуется то, после запроса выше можно сделать данный столбец NOT NULL и дефолтным значением назначить 0

`alter table Ticket alter column foiz_sub float NOT NULL default 0`

После данных процедур можно будет спокойно выполнять ваш update

`update TICKET set voz_sub_som = (select foiz_sub * tarif_som / 100 AS "Total Cost" FROM  TICKET)`

Comment: Перед тем как понижать рейтинг ответа поясните за что пожалуйста

Comment: рейтинг понижают потому, что вы даете довольно таки вредный совет - испортить данные. NULL не является источником ошибок, он несет в себе информацию о том, что данных именно НЕТ. А уж как работать с такими данными - зависит от бизнес-логики. Вы же предлагаете огульно влупить туда 0.

Comment: @gbg спасибо за комментарий, отредактировал, как вариант логики ответ думаю оставлю